# Access build parameters in Extended Choice Parameter - in promotion step?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

When promoting a build, I want to expose some choices of how/what to promote. To do this properly, I need some info about the build which I am promoting, and I'd really like to use the Extended Choice Parameter to do this.

How can I access a build's parameters in an Extended Choice Parameter block in a build promotion step? For example, say the build I want to promote was built with a parameter `myvar="1,2,5"`, and I want to let the build promoter select 1, 2, 5, or some combination. How can I access that particular build's `myvar` value, in an extended choice parameter, in a promotion process?

I can auto-populate these with available Git branches for a certain repo, with global environment variables, but I haven't seen the groovy magic I need to access info about the build I'm (about to) promote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was not obvious to me, but I found that environment variables such as `PROMOTED_URL`, `PROMOTED_JOB_NAME`, etc, were not available until the promotion steps were in progress. I need this information exposed when the promotion parameters are being populated via Extended Choice Parameter's Groovy Script fields. I accomplished it by peeking into the thread name:

```groovy
import jenkins.*
import jenkins.model.*
import hudson.*
import hudson.model.*

def jenkins = Jenkins.instance
def thread = Thread.currentThread().toString()
def (jobName,buildNumber) = thread.replaceAll(/.*GET \/job\/(.*)\/promotion\/.*/, '$1').split('/')
def job = jenkins.getJob(jobName)
def build = job.getBuild(buildNumber)

return build.getBuildVariables()["SOME_BUILD_PARAM"]
```

What do I use this for? Say I can select certain targets to build but not others, when building. I want to be able to promote only some subset of those *that were actually built*, so the parameter can't just hold a default value. Pretty narrow edge-case, I'll grant, but sometimes it seems like my entire life, as far as Jenkins is concerned, is dealing with some edge-case or another. If there is a more elegant way, I am all ears!

Answer (score 0):

building on the @courtlandj solution (with the latest hudson API):

```
import hudson.model.*

def paramToLookup = "SOME_BUILD_VARIABLE_NAME"

// you can of course parse the jobName from the currentThread
// but that is a case-by-case basis depending on how you name them
// build numbers are strictly numeric - and more predictable to parse with regex
def jobName = "some-jenkins-full-job-name"
int buildNumber = 0

// Similar approach to courtlandj to get THIS build number (of page being viewed):
def thisPromotionInfo = Thread.currentThread().toString()

// groovy regex that gets the promotion digits (\d)
def buildRegex = /.*\/(\d+)\/promotion\/.*/
def matcher = ( thisPromotionInfo =~ buildRegex )

if (matcher.matches()) {
  buildNumber = matcher[0][1].toInteger()
} else {
  return "unable to identify buildNumber in Extended Choice Parameter (see Jenkins Config)"
}

// borrowed slightly from here: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Display+job+parameters
try {
  def job = Hudson.instance.getItemByFullName(jobName)
  def build = job.getBuildByNumber(buildNumber)
  return build.getProperties()["buildVariableResolver"].resolve(paramToLookup).toString()
} catch(Exception ex) {
    return ex.toString()
}
```

relevant links I borrowed from:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jenkinsci-users/cHClVbjuSN4
http://groovy.jmiguel.eu/groovy.codehaus.org/Tutorial+5+-+Capturing+regex+groups.html
http://hudson-ci.org/javadoc/hudson/model/Hudson.html